# Remove Mac OS X from disk without erasing it

Tags: macos, hard-drive, install

I have many hard drives on my Mac. Several of them have one version or another of macOS. Most importantly:

Disk A: Sierra. I boot from this disk
Disk B: /Users directory and High Sierra. I do not boot from this disk.

I want to remove High Sierra from Disk B without touching my Users directory, any user data, or erasing the disk.
How should I proceed?

Comment: RE: "Disk B: User's directory and High Sierra. I do not boot from this disk." -- Are you referring to the `Users` _directory_ that is in the _root_ of the e.g. **Macintosh HD** when booted from **macOS High Sierra** and does this have anything to do with **macOS Sierra**?  In other words, is the `Users` _directory_ on Disk B only being used by **macOS High Sierra** or it it also been used by **macOS Sierra** too?

Comment: I don't boot from High Sierra. That install doesn't work. The Sierra boot disk uses the /Users directory on Disk B.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and safest method would be to make sure your backup is up-to-date, erase the disk and restore that part which you want to keep.

Other methods run the risk of deleting something you want to keep or keeping something that you want to delete.